# responsive menu not working while using Divi theme

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I had to create a custom page borrowing the Divi theme code in order to use my shopping carts include file. The problem is the responsible WP menu will not work on the custom pages.

Is there are anyone who has had this issue who could help? It seems like the problem is in the page container and its overlapping the menu - but am struggling to pin point the problem.

Link to a test page: https://hookedonsunshine.co/products2.php

Comment: script error in your console. so responsive menu not working

Comment: hey Vel, any idea where the error is? many thanks in advance

Comment: You can see in console